# How to push next navigation controller with Parse Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, authentication

Im am trying to figure out how to push a new `View Controller` after a user logins using **Parse Facebook login**.

The initial `View Controller` is the login page with a facebook login button.
I tried doing a the `segue` and `storyboard` push progrmatically but ended up with the facebook login failed when adding the code.

Any Ideas?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 - (IBAction)fbLoginBtnPress:(id)sender {
[self loginWithFacebook];
}

- (void)loginWithFacebook {
// Set permissions required from the facebook user account

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");   
    }
       }];
  }
```